# Is it possible to determine programmatically whether a file move will result in a copy?

Tags: java

My Java program needs to synchronously move a file on a server, ie. within the same set of local file systems. The obvious solution is to use [Files.move()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).  However, I've read that in some cases, eg. across file systems, a move will fall-back to copy-and-delete. As I'm moving large files I'd like to be able to report progress to the user if a copy take places (as there will be a noticeable delay).

However, I cannot find a simple way to do this with the Java API. I could potentially write my own copy routine that reports progress, but then I would need to know if the move is going to result in a copy.

One possibility seems to be something like:

```
try {
    Files.move(src, dest, CopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
} catch (AtomicMoveNotSupportedException  e) {
    // Perform a copy instead (and report progress)
}
```

However it's not clear to me from the Java doco if this would be correct in all cases. Is this indeed a correct solution? If not, is there another way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your solution is fine.

Although it is not actually the filesystems that change move into copy. **Atomic operation** is an operation that takes place **on same physical device**, meaning that `Files.move(..,..,CopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE)` will always succeed unless you copy to another drive OR if filesystem or OS for some reason does not support atomic operations. Meaning you can have `/dev/sda/` and `/dev/sdb`, both with `ext4` filesystem and you CANNOT perform atomic move from one to another.